# LD seemingly ignores the specified libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glut, glew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opengl linux undefined reference to basic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000925/opengl-linux-undefined-reference-to-basic-functions)

I'm trying to link a sample OpenGL program from a university course, this is the invocation:

```
$ g++ -o test -lGLEW -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lCg main.cpp
```

Despite the fact that these libraries are installed and the linker does find them (it does not complain like if I were to mistype the name of one of them), I get linker errors for all used library functions. This is the output (clipped for brevity, it is a lot longer):

```
$ g++ -o test -lGLEW -lglut -lGL -lGLU -L/usr/lib main.cpp 
/tmp/ccTo5FlN.o: In function `init()':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `glewInit'
main.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `glEnable'
main.cpp:(.text+0x593): undefined reference to `gluLookAt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `cgGLDisableProfile'
main.cpp:(.text+0x73b): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
```

Additional diagnostic information:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
$ g++ -v -o test -lGLEW -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lCg main.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/cc8sHxzT.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include  search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 65b5171ac1bd7b3f07dbea6bdb24be3d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as --64 -o /tmp/ccIov0RZ.o /tmp/cc8sHxzT.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../.. -lGLEW -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lCg /tmp/ccIov0RZ.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

This is a 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 system. What could be the problem?

Comment: Put main.cpp before the libs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000925/opengl-linux-undefined-reference-to-basic-functions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989